# CS50 Pset 2. My crack.c code compiles and runs but does not print anything

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on Pset 2 crack.c and so far and I've managed to get the general concept. However, my code still doesn't work. It compiles and runs but does NOT print anything.

I am not entirely sure what is wrong here perhaps, I may be overlooking something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

char plaintext[4];
char salt [3];
string alphapool;
string newhash;

int main (int argc, string argv[]) {


   if (argc != 2)
   {
       printf("Error: Input 2 command line arguments\n");
       return 1;
   }

   else

   {
       alphapool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./";
       salt[0] = argv[1][0]; salt[1] = argv[1][1]; salt[2] = '\0';

       //match a plaintext guess to an array in possibilities (alpha pool)
       //for one letter

       for(int i = 0; i < 26+26; i++)

       { //single letter
           plaintext[0] = alphapool[i];
           plaintext[1] = '\0';

           newhash = crypt(plaintext, salt);

           if ((strncmp(argv[1], newhash,13)) == 0)
           {
               printf("Match found, password is %s",plaintext);
               return true;
           }
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < 26+26; i++)

       {//double letter
          plaintext[0] = alphapool[i];

          for(int j = 0; j < 26+26; j++)
          {
            plaintext[1] = alphapool[i];
            plaintext[2] = '\0';

            newhash = crypt(plaintext, salt);

           if ((strncmp(argv[1], newhash,13)) == 0)
           {
               printf("Match found, password is %s", plaintext);
               return true;
           }

          }
       }

          for(int i = 0; i < 26+26; i++)
       {//three letter
          plaintext[0] = alphapool[i];

          for(int j = 0; j < 26+26; j++)
          {
            plaintext[1] = alphapool[i];

            for (int k = 0; k < 26+26; k++)
            {
                plaintext[2] = alphapool[i];
                plaintext[3] = '\0';
            }

            newhash = crypt(plaintext, salt);

           if ((strncmp(argv[1], newhash,13)) == 0)
           {
               printf("Match found, password is %s", plaintext);
               return true;
           }

       }

   }
            for(int i =0; i < 26+26; i++)
            {
                //four letter word
                  plaintext[0] = alphapool[i];

          for(int j = 0; j < 26+26; j++)
          {
            plaintext[1] = alphapool[i];

            for (int k = 0; k < 26+26; k++)
            {
                plaintext[2] = alphapool[i];

               for (int l = 0; l < 26+26; l++)
               {
                   plaintext[3] = alphapool[i];

               }


            newhash = crypt(plaintext, salt);

           if ((strncmp(argv[1], newhash,13)) == 0)
           {
               printf("Match found, password is %s", plaintext);
               return true;
           }
        }
     }
}

   return 0;

        }
}
```

I expect that plaintext generated should be the value that produced the hash which matched to the given hash.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, it supposedly executes the printf line then moves on the the next line.

Comment: Your `printf` strings don't have a newline (`\n`) at the end; could it be that it is printing it but the output gets overwritten by your prompt before you see it? (Also, did you inspect the in-memory results in the debugger, were they correct?)

Comment: added \n at the end of the printf strings. It compiled and ran, still did not print anything.

Comment: (Meanwhile some potentially unrelated observations: most of your code is inside an `else` block, but this is unnecessary since the "then" branch directly above returns from the function. And you keep repeating the magic number `26+26`, whereas you could just iterate up to the terminating NUL byte in `alphapool`. I believe you are also not iterating over the `./` in the end because of this.)

Comment: That's true, made it iterate up to the strlen of alphapool but problem still remains.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the problem seems quite obvious: you are putting `alphapool[i]` into every index of `plaintext`, when you should have `j`, `k`, etc in the inner loops.

Comment: In your inner loops for the 2-4 letter cases, you have `plaintext[1] = alphapool[i]` where you should have `plaintext[1] = alphapool[j]`, and so on. Also, for the four letter passwords you don't append a null byte to the password (and you don't have enough space for it in the `plaintext` array anyway), so `crypt()` will keep reading bytes past the end of the array (and probably into the salt, although really anything could happen). Oh, and for the 3-4 letter cases your `crypt()` call and `strncmp()` test should be inside the _innermost_ loop. Fix those things, and your code should work.

Comment: Are we magically supposed to know what PSET2 crack.c is ? Don't you think it would be important to explain the problem in the question? Better yet, just visit cs50.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The outputed strings are probably buffered, you should use `fflush` (cf man page) before returning from the program to force the buffer to be written in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `alphapool[i]` into every index of `plaintext`, when you should have `j`, `k`, and `l` in the inner loops. Also, you need to put the `crypt` (and the string comparison check of the results) inside the *innermost* loop for each password length. And, you are not putting the terminating `'\0'` in `plaintext` for password length 4 - but `plaintext` also doesn't have enough space for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I was putting alphapool[I] in all the loops. I changed it to match j, k and l. as it should. I also changed the position of the curly brackets for the kth and lth characters. It confined values and alpha pool[k] and alphapool[I] and prevented them from printing. It works now!